# Facebook Graph API: Get events using location and sort by Date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to get events from Facebook using following request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/search?q=Texas&type=event
```

But the response is not in sorted order of date. Could I get the events in sorted order from today to upcoming events.

Comment: No, the search endpoint does not offer any such sorting of the results. You’d need to implement that on your end.

Comment: @CBroe ok, one more query: is there any API limit, I mean the next page url that it generates with each request, is there any limit to it.

Comment: Theoretically not.

Comment: Did you mean limit the number of events per response? You can do that with something like this `limit=5`. Still haven't figured out how to sort by date though. :-\